# Submit button with redirect not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

```
<form name="gerirvolform" id="gerirvolform">
 <div align="center">
  <input name="infoidhidden" type="hidden" id="infoidhidden" value="<?php echo $row_gerirvoluntarios['info_id'] ?>">
  <input name="inscrever" type="submit" id="inscrever" formaction="inscreverturnovol.php" formmethod="GET" value="Inscrever Turno">
  <input name="mudarturnos" type="submit" id="mudarturnos" formaction="mudarturnovol.php" formmethod="GET" value="Mudar Turnos">
  <input name="apagar" type="submit" id="apagar" formmethod="POST" value="Apagar Voluntário">
 </div>
</form>
```

So this is the code I have currently this works fine for any computer and any browser on pc/mac.
The issue is i've had 2 phones(wiko, samsung galaxy s5) that when I click one of the buttons (inscrever, mudarturno) the website does nothing, I've tried with other phones they all work.

The logs:

```
"GET /Account.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1109 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

"GET /editarvoluntario.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4740 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

"GET /inscreverturnovol.php?infoidhidden=9&inscrever=Inscrever+Turno HTTP/1.1" 200 2685 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

These are from the correct way it should work.

```
"GET /Account.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1109 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GETAWAY Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

"GET /editarvoluntario.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4617 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GETAWAY Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

"GET /editarvoluntario.php?infoidhidden=9&inscrever=Inscrever+Turno HTTP/1.1" 200 4617 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GETAWAY Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

These are from one of the phones that doesn't work correctly the code posted before is on editarvoluntario.php.

I've tried to search the web for info but I don't seem to be able to find any anywhere

Comment: seems like they both return 200 ok. Which means it's working...

Comment: maybe the mobile browser doesn't support the formaction attribute. The mozilla site might be of help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button - near the bottom of the page and under the mobile tab.

Comment: What happens when you change the type of the buttons to button and use  javascript to do the submit?

Answer (score 1):

u have add method in input tag.u need to add method attribute in form and action attribute in form. so,that the,browser will know where to,send data and what method to be used.

Comment: The form has different methods and different action for different buttons inside it so defining those parameters in the form isn't the solution I was looking for